# Функция preg_match и ее условия...

Tags: php

Здравствуйте у меня вопрос.
Вот у меня есть такая строка

```
preg_match("/^((?:\%?\<[^\>]{2,20}\>\s?)+)(.*?)$/", $msg, $arr);
```

она высеивает сообщение типа "<Слово> слово" или "%<Слово> слово"
разбивает его на array
так-же есть второе условие

```
preg_match("/^((?:\%clan%\s?)+)(.*?)$/", $msg, $arr);
```

она высеивает сообщение типа "%clan% слово", "%clan% <Слово> слово" или "%clan% %<Слово> слово"
Совместив это 2 условия у меня получилось

```
preg_match("/^((?:\%clan\%\s?)?(?:\%?\<[^\>]{2,20}\>\s?)?+)(.*?)$/", $msg, $arr);
```

но есть один минус, если нету этих условий "%clan% слово", "%clan%<слово> слово", "%<слово> слово" или "<слово> слово" и тд. то он создает массив из простого "слово" где переменная **$arr[2]** пустая, а как сделать так чтоб **$arr** вообще не создавалось?

Comment: а trim перед preg_match не поможет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(empty($arr[2])){
unset($arr);
}
```

не?
`*`trollface`*`

Comment: Ладно спасибо за ответ, хоть не то что искал, но покамись возьму твою идею, правда она у меня уже давно была)

Comment: if(!isset($arr[2])){ ... }